# Exponentially smaller intervals with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that will virtually no points from 0-99, some from 99-99.99 and some from 99.99 to hundred.  What's the easiest way to configure a bar chart so that they will be evenly spaced?

Comment: In Highcharts? Only option is to use catagories. In Highstock simply set `ordinal: true`, for xAxis [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal).

Comment: @PawełFus can you elaborate how categories would work?  Basically I want a chart that displays from 0-100 and i want ticks evenly spaced for 0, 99, 99.99 and 100.  When I tried entering those as categories for the axis I got a dozen ticks of what seemed like random points.

Comment: Sorry, but you have no points 0-99. Then USe categories only for points: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/95/

Comment: @PawełFus This is closer to what I'm trying to do, and you can see the issue I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/97

Comment: Ah, you mean bar chart, missed that. Scale breaks are not supported by Highcharts.